Splash Screen Background image doesn't work could you help me

flutter_native_splash:
android: true
ios: true
web: false
color: "#42a5f5" // Just test
background_image: "assets/splash.png"
android_12:
I want to make a png image a background and not an icon, using the flutter_native_splash package. Everything is correct. Obviously there's a problem with the image but I can't solve it. I've increased and decreased the resolution but it didn't work. I activated the image in Assets, no problem, I can already make icon there, I just can't do it for the background. Can you help me?

As per the libraries docs, android 12 does not support background image, it must use an icon, background colour etc, you can either specify a new icon or it will use the app icon.
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash#android-12-support
